# MFC COutlookBar Detect Click on Pane

Tags: events, mfc

I have an application with a CMFCOutlookBar located on the left pane. I added three panes on the OutlookBar with three buttons on the bottom. Everything works so far...

I tried but did not succeed to detect when there is a click on the different buttons located at the bottom of the CMFCOutlookBar.

Is it possible to intercept such event ?

Comment: Yes of course it's possible. There's is more than one way to do this - what did you try so far? Can you show your code?

Comment: Well, I derive a new class from CMFCOutlokkBar and I add OnNotify, OnLButtonDowna nd OnLButtonUp but the associated messages are not sent to the derived class ....Of course, I have a MESSAGE_MAP in the class ...

Comment: How does your code compare with the MS example? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee837238.aspx

Comment: Hello Roger
Well, my application uses the complete Outlookbar as shown in the sample OutlookDemo ... But you trigger the way to a solution ..
I derived a new class from CMFCOutlookBarPane and I succeed to got some messages... Basically, I find that OnEraseBkgnd is acceptable as a workaround even if it is called many times ...
Thanks for your help .... 
Thierry